# How do I clone a generic List in Java?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, clone

I have an `ArrayList<String>` that I'd like to return a copy of.  `ArrayList` has a clone method which has the following signature:

```
public Object clone()
```

After I call this method, how do I cast the returned Object back to `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: No, this is a valid question.  Java does not support "true" generics, with runtime type erasure and all, so these kinds of details can be tricky.  Furthermore, the Cloneable interface and the Object.clone() method mechanism is similarly confusing.

Comment: OK, I mostly do C# where this is really easy. Please let me know if you want me to remove the comments from this question.

Comment: You can leave the comment.  I think my edits explained what I was having trouble with.

Comment: Your comment is OK, if a bit condescending.  I imagine a lot of hoops that Java developers have to jump through seem silly to .NET developers.

Comment: Uh?... What was the problem again? I didn't quite get it. The question was "How to invoke clone on List interface?" I think problem is the same for generic or not generic lists. Was that the question? or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Oscar, he wants to clone, and not to invoke the clone command. It may not be the same it the clone doesn't really clones. I think this is the point. This is indeed a tricky question.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Do you prefer the 30(ish) upvote answer or have you just not revisited it since the 180(ish) answer was posted?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
ArrayList newArrayList = (ArrayList) oldArrayList.clone();
```

Comment: This will work fine for Strings (which is what the question asked for), but it is worth noting that ArrayList.clone will perform a shallow copy, so if there were mutable objects in the list, they will not be cloned (and changing one in one list will change that one in the other list as well.

Comment: You should avoid using raw types in anything but legacy code.  You're better off using `ArrayList<String> newArrayList = (ArrayList<String>) oldArrayList.clone();`.

Comment: It's too bad ArrayList has a #clone method, but List itself doesn't. Sigh.

Comment: Not related but while at it: use `List<String>` instead of `ArrayList<String>` on the left-hand side. This is how collections should be used most of the time.

Comment: I could not use this method to duplicate an ArrayList. The clone() method was not recognized.

Comment: @Jack, the mistake in your case is that you try to call clone() method via List interface, not via ArrayList class.

Answer (score 352):

Why would you want to clone? Creating a new list usually makes more sense.

```
List<String> strs;
...
List<String> newStrs = new ArrayList<>(strs);
```

Job done.

Comment: You may not know what type of List it is. It might be a LinkedList, MyOwnCustomList or a subclass of ArrayList, in which case newing an ArrayList would be the incorrect type.

Comment: Would I care which implementation the original list used? I probably care which implementation the new list uses.

Comment: @Steve Kuo: The signature is `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` meaning it doesn't matter what kind of list you use as an argument.

Comment: cdmckay, the issue is about the behaviour of the new List. For ArrayList vs LinkedList, what should it's performance characteristics be. I say it should be what the copying code asks for. Steve Kuo appears to believe that it should be whatever the original list happened to be.

Comment: According to documentation [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) it seems not to copy the element of the list but to use the same references, am I right?

Comment: I mean it isn't a deep copy, is it?

Comment: @YekhezkelYovel No, it wouldn't be.

Comment: But clone is deep copy. So, copy constructor vs. clone are different, then?

Comment: @Vlad No. If you cloned say`ArrayList<Date>` then any modifications to dates in one list would be reflected in the other.

Comment: This isn't a deep copy though

Comment: @Inchara Neither is `ArrayList.clone`.

Comment: I don't think this is deep copy. `strs.list` still referenced.

Comment: @PasupathiRajamanickam No it's still not a deep copy. As original question, it's the equivalent of cloning the list.

Comment: Would be good if this answer explained the advantages of creating a new list over cloning a list.

Answer (score 19):

This is the code I use for that:

```
ArrayList copy = new ArrayList (original.size());
Collections.copy(copy, original);
```

Hope is usefull for you

Comment: And avoid using raw types.. so instead of `ArrayList` use `ArrayList<YourObject>`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy-java.util.List-java.util.List-

Doesn't work because the list sizes are different.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the copying overload of the `ArrayList` constructor?

Answer (score 19):

With Java 8 it can be cloned with a stream.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

...

```
List<AnObject> clone = myList.stream().collect(toList());
```

Comment: Can be done like List<AnObject> xy = new ArrayList<>(oldList);

Comment: This is not a deep copy, changes on one list's elements can be seen in another

Comment: Where in the question does it specify a deep copy is required? The assumption is that another collection containing the same objects is required. If you want to go down the deep copy route then you are opening up a whole new can of worms.

Comment: Not really a clone though, is it? From the API docs "There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned". Euw, don't want one of those. `toCollection` may be a better choice.

Comment: Why has this answer so many upvotes?! Question clearly asks for a clone, i.e. a deep copy, please downvote this answer!

Answer (score 17):

Be advised that Object.clone() has some major problems, and its use is discouraged in most cases. Please see Item 11, from "[Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)" by Joshua Bloch for a complete answer. I believe you can safely use Object.clone() on primitive type arrays, but apart from that you need to be judicious about properly using and overriding clone. You are probably better off defining a copy constructor or a static factory method that explicitly clones the object according to your semantics.

Answer (score 15):

I think this should do the trick using the Collections API:

**Note**: the copy method runs in linear time.

```
//assume oldList exists and has data in it.
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.copy(newList, oldList);
```

Comment: Why not just use new ArrayList<String>(oldList) ?

Comment: I believe this wouldn't work, from doc * The destination list must be at least as long as the source list.  If it is longer, the remaining elements in the destination list are unaffected.

Comment: @GregDomjan not that i agree that this is the best way, but it's a way to do it. To get around your issue it's as simeple as this:  List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(oldList.size());

Comment: Not sure if it's related to Java 8, but even when specifying the size, still getting an exception *IndexOutOfBoundsException: destination.size() < source.size(): 0 < 2* on `List<MySerializableObject> copyList = new ArrayList<>(mMySerializableObjects.size());`  It seems using `copyList.addAll(original);` is a good alternative

Comment: @GeneBo It isn't specifying the size. It's specifying the capacity, which is a very different thing. The joy of mystery `int` arguments. I've no idea why you want to use this obscure static method instead of good old `addAll`.

Answer (score 12):

I find using addAll works fine.

```
ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>();
copy.addAll(original);
```

parentheses are used rather than the generics syntax

Comment: That'll work for Strings, but not for mutable objects.  You'll want to clone those as well.

Comment: Yeah, his question is for strings.  And he has the problem of generics which don't really like the casting stuff in this case.

Comment: Also, ArrayList.clone will only do a shallow clone, so mutable objects in the list won't be cloned using that method either.

Comment: That should be ArrayList<String> btw.  Also, you're probably better off using new ArrayList<String>(original) as it's less writing and just as clear.

Comment: Why not just use `new ArrayList<String>(original)` ?

Comment: Looking at the OpenJDK 8 source code, using `List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(original);` has the added benefit of less overhead and might be a tiiiny bit quicker compared to `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(original); list.addAll(orig);` (haven't tested, although using constructor arguments instead of `addAll(Collection)` just for the performance benefit delves into the premature optimization territory, I just use it because it's shorter tbh)

Answer (score 8):

```
List<String> shallowClonedList = new ArrayList<>(listOfStrings);
```

Keep in mind that this is only a shallow not a deep copy, ie. you get a new list, but the entries are the same. This is no problem for simply strings. Get's more tricky when the list entries are objects themself.

Answer (score 7):

If you want this in order to be able to return the List in a getter it would be better to do:

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(list);
```

Answer (score 4):

To clone a generic interface like `java.util.List` you will just need to cast it. here you are an example:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
List list2 = ((List) ( (ArrayList) list).clone());
```

It is a bit tricky, but it works, if you are limited to return a `List` interface, so anyone after you can implement your list whenever he wants.

I know this answer is close to the final answer, but my answer answers how to do all of that while you are working with `List` -the generic parent- not `ArrayList`

Comment: you are assuming that it will always be an ArrayList which is not true

Comment: @JuanCarlosDiaz will, this is the question asked, it was about ArrayList, so I answered it for ArrayList :)

Answer (score 3):

Be very careful when cloning ArrayLists. Cloning in java is shallow. This means that it will  only clone the Arraylist itself and not its members. So if you have an ArrayList X1 and clone it into X2 any change in X2 will also manifest in X1 and vice-versa. When you clone you will only generate a new ArrayList with pointers to the same elements in the original.

Answer (score 2):

This should also work:

```
ArrayList<String> orig = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> copy = (ArrayList<String>) orig.clone()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList first = new ArrayList ();
ArrayList copy = (ArrayList) first.clone ();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a java professional, but I have the same problem and I tried to solve by this method. (It suppose that T has a copy constructor).

```
 public static <T extends Object> List<T> clone(List<T> list) {
      try {
           List<T> c = list.getClass().newInstance();
           for(T t: list) {
             T copy = (T) t.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(t.getclass()).newInstance(t);
             c.add(copy);
           }
           return c;
      } catch(Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException("List cloning unsupported",e);
      }
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the `List` implementation class has a public no-arg constructor. For instance, the `List`s returns by `Array.asList`, `List.of` or `List.subList` probably don't.