# Java unsafe or unchecked expressions: cloning an arraylist

Tags: java, compiler-errors, type-safety

I got the unchecked expression error when compiling and found the offending line to be

```
ArrayList<Integer> items = (ArrayList<Integer>) this.items.clone();
```

I am trying to perform a deep copy of my object so I am cloning a property of the object and array list in the above manner. How can I fix this warning?

- I could use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` but that is just hiding the problem (tho I expect none)
- If I clone manually by looping through all elements to it will be slower I think

Whats the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your elements are Integers, performing a "deep copy" really isn't an issue, since there's no reason why you would need to copy an Integer object.  Just use `new ArrayList<Integer>(this.items)`.

But for reference, neither clone() nor the ArrayList copy constructor will do a deep copy.  It's only because your element types don't need deep copying that this satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same behavior with `new ArrayList<Integer>(this.items)`. Either way, though, it's a **shallow** copy.

[API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone%28%29)

Comment: Of course, there's no real need to make a deep copy of `Integer` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Integers are immutable, so it doesn't matter if you make a deep copy or not.

use the Collections utility class in java.util:

```
import java.util.Collections;
...
ArrayList<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>(this.items.size());
Collections.copy(items, this.items);
```

Comment: `Arrays.copyOf` doesn't return an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Oops, meant Collections.copy, not Arrays.copyOf.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the backwards compatibility required when they introduced generics to the Java API, there's no way around using casting and `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in some situations.

Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-java) for a reason why `clone()` usage should be used with care: it does a shallow copy, which is fine for primatives, but is dangerous with objects.

Comment: You can put primitives in `ArrayLists`s? I thought you could only put objects, and at best wrappers for primitives.

Comment: @blahman The point was that primitive fields are fine when cloning, but object fields (like `ArrayList<Integer> items`) are sources of trouble.

Comment: Oh...oops. Totally missed that. Sorry, Yuushi. My bad ^^' Also, thanks @TedHopp =)

Answer (score 0):

You've said you're trying to do a deep copy, but as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents), I doubt you'll be able to do that using `clone()`. So, like the other posters have said, it is a somewhat more hazardous method to use `clone()` and you won't be able to get the deep copy you've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, cloning the `ArrayList` does not clone its elements. If you want to make a deep copy of the contents, there's a neat trick: serialize and deserialize the array. (This works because `ArrayList` and `Integer` both implement `Serializable`.) However, this doesn't get rid of the need to suppress unchecked conversion warnings.

```
// Write the object out to a byte array
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
out.writeObject(this.items);
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

// Retrieve an input stream from the byte array and read
// a copy of the object back in.
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
ArrayList<Integer> items = (ArrayList<Integer>) in.readObject();
```

If your entire object can be declared Serializable, you could use this instead of a clone operation to make your deep copy. Also, see [this article](http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/) for a way to avoid the expense of copying the bytes out of the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.