# clone() method in LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I am learning java and going over the collections framework currently. I am trying out the API methods for LinkedList and am facing problem with the clone() method. Below is my code

```
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LinkedListTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] colors1 = {"Red", "Blue"};

        List<String> color1List = new LinkedList<String>();

        for(String color:colors1)
            color1List.add(color);

        List clonedList = (LinkedList) color1List.clone();
    }
}
```

When I compile this program, I get the following Error:

```
LinkedListTest.java:51: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method clone()
location: interface java.util.List<java.lang.String>
                List<String> clonedList = (LinkedList<String>)color1List.clone();
                                                                    ^
1 error
```

I tried to lookup but was unsuccessful in finding any reason. What is wrong with the program??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List doesnt have a clone method.
change that to:

```
LinkedList<String> color1List = new LinkedList<String>();
```

if you want to leave it a list, you'll have to do something a little ugly like:

```
List clonedList = (LinkedList) ((LinkedList) color1List).clone();
```

Comment: The method `clone()` is available in the `Object` class. So I was struggling with why the compiler is unable to find this method. Thank you so much for your answer we have to typecast it. This makes sense

Answer (score -1):

The List class does not have a clone method. See here:

[How do I clone a generic List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-java)

Consider using ArrayList instead, given all the objects stored are Strings.