# Java list changed when update another one

Tags: java

Supposing we have:

```
public class Test {

    private List<String> mWorkList;
    private List<String> mOriginalList;

    public Test(List<String> list) {
        mWorkList = list;
        mOriginalList = list;
    }

    public void updateData(List<String> newList) {
        mWorkList.clear();
        mWorkList.addAll(newList);
    }
}
```

I want to change only `mWorkList` but `mOriginalList` is changed too when I call `updateData(List<String>)`. 
So how should I do it to keep `mOriginalList` as initially assigned in constructor?

Comment: Both point to the same instance of `List<String> list`... you need to create a new instance of `List`, see how to duplicate the list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56383/4391450) into a new instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java you pass variables by their **reference**. This means that whenever you do an assignment like `mWorkList = list` the variable `mWorkList` will point to **the same** place in memory where `list` is currently pointing. If you do `mOriginalList = list`, then `mOriginalList` will also point to that position. I.e. **all three lists** refer **the same object** at that point.

---

If you want independent lists you need to **copy** all values from the list to a **new list** like this:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(otherList);
```

This constructor of `ArrayList` automatically adds all values from the other list, here is its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-).

---

Your code could then look like:

```
public Test(List<String> list) {
    mWorkList = new ArrayList<>(list);
    mOriginalList = new ArrayList<>(list);
}
```

Or if you don't intent to change `mOriginalList` you could also leave it as `mOriginalList = list`. But then bear in mind that if the user makes changes to `list` (which comes from *outside* of your class) they will also be reflected in your `mOriginalList` which could easily lead to **nasty bugs**.

Answer (score 4):

You should create new `List` object in function `Test`, because all your lists refer to one variable

```
public Test(List<String> list) {
    mWorkList = new ArrayList<>(list);
    mOriginalList = new ArrayList<>(list);
}
```

Comment: to elaborate: have different references to list as above. Then you use mWorkList.addAll(list); mOriginalList.addAll() to populate the data in lists

Comment: @YegorBabarykin OP must wait at least **15 minutes** to be able to accept. This ensures that others also have a chance to post good answers ([Time limit on accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer)).

Comment: @Zabuza Thanks, i didn't know this rule

Answer (score 4):

You are setting both list with the same instance reference with

```
mWorkList = list;
mOriginalList = list;
```

You need to create a new instance for `mOriginalList` by duplicating the list. This can be done with one of the constructor of [`ArrayList(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-).

```
mOriginalList = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

Please note that the instances in both list are the same, so if you update an instance in `list`, it will be changed in `mOriginalList`. If you want to break that link too, you will need to clone the list and his content.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you assign a object to another object only the reference is assigned (Shallow copy). You should call copy constructor to make a deep copy.

```
public class Test {

    private List<String> mWorkList;
    private List<String> mOriginalList;


    public Test(List<String> list) {
        mWorkList = new ArrayList<>(list);
        mOriginalList = new ArrayList<>(list);
    }

    public void updateData(List<String> newList) {
        mWorkList.clear();
        mWorkList.addAll(newList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In java every variable is a reference, so in this case it's normal that both variable changes if you change one of them.

To keep a copy you have to create a new object and clone the original one.