# ArrayList inside an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I came across a problem in which I had to use nested ArrayList in java and had to clear the innerlist after each iteration. I noticed that when I added the innerlist to the main list and cleared the innerlist later , the value of the main list changed . Can anyone please explain why this is happening . Also , will there be any change if I use array instead of ArrayList. I have attached the code to my problem below to make it clear.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Example
{


     public static void main(String []args){
        
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list= new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> innerlist = new ArrayList<>();
        innerlist.add(1);
        list.add(innerlist);
        System.out.println(list);
        innerlist.clear();
        System.out.println(list);
}
 
}
```

Output :
[[1]]
[[]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) doesn't copy anything - it just adds a reference to the object you pass as parameter to the end of the list. If you want that changes to the `innerlist` reference don't affect your `list` at all, you need to copy it, for example using the [constructor taking a Collection parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)). You can do this either when adding

```
list.add(new ArrayList<>(innerlist));
```

or you reassign `innerlist` to a new list after adding

```
list.add(innerlist);
innerlist = new ArrayList<>();
```

especially if you need to clear it anyway at that point.
See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177561/java-list-changed-when-update-another-one), which handles the same problem, but without an outer list.

Answer (score 0):

`innerlist` is pointing still pointing to the ArrayList.

Check this:
[What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)